# Creating a single PDF from a lot of image

Tags: 14.04, pdf, convert

I have a lot of image files. I want to convert them to one single pdf file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 12):

First, install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then in the images folder, do something like:

```
convert *.png out.pdf
```

Maybe you can do `convert * out.pdf`.(I didn' t try this one). Otherwise, You can convert other images to png first then do above. For more details see doc of imagemagick convert command.